# When to use ElementFactory method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, binding

I am using springs AutoPopulateList using following
METHOD 1

```
 passports = new AutoPopulatingList<Passport>(Passport.class);
```

METHOD2
and also first creating Passportfactory

```
public class PassportFactory implements AutoPopulatingList.ElementFactory {
  private Person person;

  public PassportFactory(Person person) {
     this.person = person;
  }

  public Object createElement(int index) {
    Passport passport = new Passport();
    passport.setPerson(person);
    return passport;
  }
}
```

and then using this

```
List<Passport> passports = new AutoPopulatingList(new PassportFactory(this));
```

Now both codes are working but i don't know what is the difference between two and how second code will be helpful because copied from internet. Can someone explain me the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use:

`passports = new AutoPopulatingList<Passport>(Passport.class);` Spring will use an `ReflectiveElementFactory<E>` to create elements.

This mean for example that your list elements must have a none parameter constructor.

But if you do not have such a constructor for your list elements, or need to build the elements in a special way, than you need to create your own `ElementFactory`. -- For example your second code, set the `person` field in every create list element, while the first one will leave this field empty.

Comment: I also thought the same but my problem was that i have person_id field as foreign key in passport table , which was auto increment in person table. Now it was  always empty. i thought hibernate will insert in passport table but it didn't but then i used this "for(Passport passport : person.getPassports())
   {
       passport.setPerson(person);
   }

   
   session.save(person)" in service class and then it inserted. Is this thing possible without explicitly setting person

Comment: @Pasha: I do not really understand your comment, but it seams to be an other question than: When to use ElementFactory method in Spring. So open an new (Hibernate related) question, and add post your hibernate relevant stuff (mappings, session handling) too.